# Chrome: Disable mouse wheel elastic scroll at end of webpages

Tags: macos, google-chrome

It *seems* that with Google Chrome Version 51.0.2704.84 (or very recently) has introduced an "elastic rubber band" effect when you try to scroll past the top or bottom of a webpage, with a ***mouse wheel*** (*scroll wheel*).

I am using OS X, and have never seen this behavior before in Chrome.

I find that the rubber band effect can be useful on touch devices, but I don't need it when using mice with desktop computers. When I scroll to the very end with my mouse wheel, that's typically where I want to go, and the rubber band effect is just an annoyance and delays further action.

I checked in *chrome://flags*, but can't seem to find  a setting. Not sure.

---

**Update 2016-09-04**: This "problem" has now gone away, and the inertia setting is back to it's previous "immediate stop" behaviour when scrolling to page ends with a mouse wheel. I'm not sure what changed, but might've been a Google Chrome update. I have accepted the answer below, in case it helps somebody with a particular flavour of the issue.

Comment: Exactly the same problem here. I love the elastic scroll on trackpads, but it just gets in the way on a regular mouse. Would love to be able to disable it, back to how it was. (I've put a bounty on here to hopefully get some more attention to the issue, all be it a small one)

Comment: See if the solution in this article applies here : [Disable elastic scrolling in OS X](http://www.cnet.com/how-to/disable-elastic-scrolling-in-os-x/). See also [TinkerTool](https://www.bresink.com/osx/0TinkerTool/details.html) for "Disable inertia" and "Disable the rubber-band effect".

Comment: @harrymc, thanks, yeah that does work, but it disables the elastic feature OS wide, I quite like this feature, just not in Chrome with a normal mouse.

Comment: As remarked in [Issue 101916](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=101916) about this OS X setting : "Chrome version 23 should respect the preference". Otherwise, using an add-on to add [this CSS code](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16327467/165358) to every displayed future page might work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Chrome is only obeying OS X system preferences.

Disabling these preferences is described in the article
[Disable elastic scrolling in OS X](http://www.cnet.com/how-to/disable-elastic-scrolling-in-os-x/).

You can also use the free [TinkerTool](https://www.bresink.com/osx/0TinkerTool/details.html). See especially the settings for
"Disable inertia" and "Disable the rubber-band effect".

If you wish to disable this only for Chrome, you will need to add this
[CSS snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16327467/165358) to every displayed future page. This is best done using
the add-on [Tampermonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo?hl=en), which is the Chrome port for Greasemonkey.

See the [Tampermonkey website](https://tampermonkey.net/) for using it.

Some more references :

- [The beginner's guide to Greasemonkey scripting](http://www.techradar.com/news/internet/the-beginner-s-guide-to-greasemonkey-scripting-598247/2)
- [Manipulating Stylesheets with Greasemonkey](https://www.abeautifulsite.net/manipulating-stylesheets-with-greasemonkey)

Comment: Not sure if it's correct that Chrome is only obeying OS X system preferences. When using the mouse wheel in Safari, scrolling does *not* produce this effect. For some reason, in Chrome the mouse wheel is behaving like a touch device. Adding the CSS code would probably disable inertia for touch pads too, right?

Comment: It should disable inertia everywhere. There was previously a [bug in Chrome](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=101916) where Chrome did not obey these preferences, which it now does. I wonder whether Safari has a similar problem. There might of course be other possible answers than mine.